# Cannot start phoenix server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I call `mix phoenix.server` I am getting the following error. I have tried restarting my computer.

## Versions:

macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195)

Elixir 1.4.2

## Dependencies:

```
defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
  end
```

## Error Message:

```
** (EXIT from #PID<0.70.0>) an exception was raised:
    ** (File.Error) could not write to file "/Users/joseph/sites/super/_build/dev/consolidated/Elixir.Ecto.Queryable.beam": permission denied
        (elixir) lib/file.ex:719: File.write!/3
        (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.protocols.ex:127: Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protocols.consolidate/4
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:85: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:36: Task.Supervised.reply/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3

21:03:23.486 [error] Task #PID<0.185.0> started from #PID<0.70.0> terminating
** (File.Error) could not write to file "/Users/joseph/sites/super/_build/dev/consolidated/Elixir.Poison.Decoder.beam": permission denied
    (elixir) lib/file.ex:719: File.write!/3
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.protocols.ex:127: Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protocols.consolidate/4
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:85: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:36: Task.Supervised.reply/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<8.61154972/0 in Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protocols.consolidate/6>
    Args: []

21:03:23.487 [error] Task #PID<0.181.0> started from #PID<0.70.0> terminating
** (File.Error) could not write to file "/Users/joseph/sites/super/_build/dev/consolidated/Elixir.Phoenix.HTML.FormData.beam": permission denied
    (elixir) lib/file.ex:719: File.write!/3
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.protocols.ex:127: Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protocols.consolidate/4
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:85: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:36: Task.Supervised.reply/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<8.61154972/0 in Mix.Tasks.Compile.Protocols.consolidate/6>
    Args: []
```

Comment: Does your user not have write access to that folder? Elixir is unable to write the compiled .beam files.

Comment: @Dogbert you are right. I tried creating a file in that directory but it didn't work. Maybe I had messed up with chmod when I was trying to deploy. But it's only for the `/consolidated` directory

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why I am encountering this issue.

But I fixed it by running `sudo chmod 777 _build/dev/consolidated` in the root directory of my application.